# Implementing Addition, subtraction, multiplication, division of numbers of different base and give result in desired base:

Tags: python, number-systems

Implement addition, subtraction, division and multiplication of given numbers of different base and provide result in desired base:

> Example:
>
> n1,b1 = 1010, 2
>
> n2,b2 = 100, 10
>
> desired_base = 9
>
> addition(n1,b1,n2,b2,desired_base) = 22
>
> subtraction(n1,b1,n2,b2,desired_base) = 0
>
> multiplication(n1,b1,n2,b2,desired_base) = 121

I have written this code, but How to improve its complexity?

```
global dict_base, dict_reverse
dict_base = {'0': 0, '1':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6,'7':7,'8':8, '9':9, 'A':10, 'B':11, 'C':12, 'D':13, 'E':14, 'F':15, 'G':16, 'H':17}
dict_reverse = {v: k for k, v in dict_base.iteritems()}
def convert_to_base_10(num_str, base):
    global dict_base
    k = 1
    ans = 0
    for char in num_str[::-1]:
        ans += dict_base[char] * k
        k = k * base
    return int(ans)    

def convert_from_base_10(num, des_base):
    global dict_reverse
    ans = []
    neg_flag = False
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    if num < 0:
        neg_flag = True
        num = num * (-1)
    while num>0:
        ans.append(dict_reverse[num % des_base])
        num = num / des_base
    if neg_flag:
        return '-'+''.join(str(digit) for digit in ans[::-1])
    return ''.join(str(digit) for digit in ans[::-1])
               
    
def addition(n1, b1, n2, b2, b):
    n1_10 = convert_to_base_10(n1,b1)
    n2_10 = convert_to_base_10(n1,b1)
    ans = n1_10 + n2_10
    ans = convert_from_base_10(ans, b)
    return ans

def subtraction(n1, b1, n2, b2, b):
    n1_10 = convert_to_base_10(n1,b1)
    n2_10 = convert_to_base_10(n1,b1)
    ans = n1_10 - n2_10
    ans = convert_from_base_10(ans, b)
    return ans

def multiplication(n1, b1, n2, b2, b):
    n1_10 = convert_to_base_10(n1,b1)
    n2_10 = convert_to_base_10(n1,b1)
    ans = n1_10 * n2_10
    ans = convert_from_base_10(ans, b)
    return ans

print subtraction('1010', 2,'100', 10, 9)
print addition('1010', 2,'100', 10, 9)
print multiplication('1010', 2,'100', 10, 9)
```

Comment: Is that a homework task or such? For real production code I won't mix up base conversion with the math operation functions at all, since I don't see much additional value  providing those functions.

Comment: If you convert everything to base 10 that way, you need to support all possible bases explicitly. For example, what if someone wants base 2047 ? I think the purpose of the homework was to have you write a general purpose module/class.

Answer (score 1):

For the conversion to base ten, you can just use the normal `int` function. It takes as a second argument a base (as int). In this case the first argument is required to be a string (so it has exactly the same interface as your `convert_to_base_10` function.

For the `convert_from_base_10` function, I would do something closer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2063535/4042267). It is recursive, which should be fine here (unless you convert numbers with more than a thousand digits in binary, because one thousand is the default maximum recursion depth in Python). It is also a lot easier to read, IMO.

Finally, your calculation functions all proceed after the same scheme:

1. Convert the inputs to decimal
2. Calculate the result in decimal
3. Convert to the desired base

For this you could define a [`decorator`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) that can wrap the actual calculation, which can then just assume everything is in base ten. So I would do:

```
def digit_to_char(digit):
    if digit < 10:
        return str(digit)
    return chr(ord('a') + digit - 10)


def str_base(number,base):
    if number < 0:
        return '-' + str_base(-number, base)
    d, m = divmod(number, base)
    if d > 0:
        return str_base(d, base) + digit_to_char(m)
    return digit_to_char(m)


def calculate_in_decimal(func):
    def wrapper(n1, b1, n2, b2, b):
        n1_10 = int(n1, b1)
        n2_10 = int(n2, b2)
        ans = func(n1_10, n2_10)
        return str_base(ans, b)


# Use it like this:
@calculate_in_decimal
def addition(n1, n2):
    return n1 + n2


# Or use the operator module:
import operator
multiplication = calculate_in_decimal(operator.mul)
subtraction = calculate_in_decimal(operator.sub)
```

Note that I also fixed a bug, you wrote:

```
n1_10 = convert_to_base_10(n1,b1)
n2_10 = convert_to_base_10(n1,b1)
```

Where it should be:

```
n1_10 = convert_to_base_10(n1,b1)
n2_10 = convert_to_base_10(n2,b2)
```